# Hibernate Same Query Multiple Aliases and Performance Issue

Tags: java, sql, performance, spring, hibernate

**Can someone explain why does Hibernate generate different aliases for the same query?**(ABC1_25, ABC1_27 ...)

*How can Hibernate be configured to reuse the same queries with same aliases? How can the query be cached or made optimal?*

The application I am working with is generating same queries with different aliases as shown below:

```
 SELECT abc0_.ATTR_ID AS ABC1_25_,
     abc0_.ALLOW AS ALLOW2_25_,
     abc0_.ALTER_DATE AS ALTER3_25_,
     abc0_.CREATE_DATE AS CREATE6_25_,
 FROM ABCTABLE abc0_
 WHERE abc0_._ID = :1

 SELECT abc0_.ATTR_ID AS ABC1_27_,
     abc0_.ALLOW AS ALLOW2_27_,
     abc0_.ALTER_DATE AS ALTER3_27_,
     abc0_.CREATE_DATE AS CREATE6_27_,
 FROM ABCTABLE abc0_
 WHERE abc0_._ID = :1
```

**This is causing processor and memory consumption.**

I came across this link:
[Hibernate produce different SQL for every query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452183/hibernate-produce-different-sql-for-every-query) but did not find an answer.

Comment: Hello. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have several instances of the `SessionFactory`, instead of using a singleton. That's what the OP of the other question found.