# Why H2 tries to drop table upon adding a new column with Liquibase changeset?

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, h2, liquibase

I'm using in-memory H2 for my Java Spring backend application's tests. I utilize Liquibase for database change managment and Hibernate as ORM framework.
My versions are:

- liquibase-core - 4.26.0
- H2 - 2.1.214
- Spring Boot - 3.1.4
- OpenJDK - 17

Recently, I've added the following changeset:

```xml
<changeSet author="author" id="0069">
    <addColumn
        schemaName= "schema"
        tableName="table">

        <column name="address_id" type="int" />
    </addColumn>
</changeSet>
```

It produces the same output for the following changeset:

```xml
<changeSet author="author" id="0069">
    <sql>
        ALTER TABLE schema.table ADD address_id INT
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

It went smooth with my real PostgreSQL database. However, when it comes to executing `@SpringBootTest` locally which runs H2 it produces the following error:

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for changeset liquibase/changelog/000069.xml::0069::author:Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException:Cannot drop "TABLE_COPY_3_186" because "TABLE_COPY_3_186_FKDKH1LTY9WPEGOSJK292PCEH0O, 
TABLE_COPY_3_186_FKEDSHLUMQ8SP6RPM2CP2QAV15V, TABLE_COPY_3_186_FKQ9TRR3YLT6JBKPA99M06Y58JD
...
...
...
depends on it; SQL statement:DROP TABLE "SCHEMA"."TABLE_COPY_3_186" [90107-214] [Failed SQL: (90107) ALTER TABLE schema.table ADD address_id INT]
```

Error itself does not suprise me as it tries deleting table with existing foreign keys and supposedly recreates it later with the new column. **Question is why it tries to do it?** I suspect some performance tweaks however it seems irresponsible to introduce such "feature". I'm looking for some elegant solution to that matter. Dropping existing constraints and recreating them later seems like over-engineering. **Have you encountered similar issue? How did you resolve it?**

It seems that problem occurs since I've upgraded h2 and some other libraries to newer versions.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Now you know why you should test against the same database as you use in production. Spend time on testing rather then troubleshooting database differences. Also even if should you cobble something together how do you know it really is an accurate test?

Comment: Thanks for your response Adrian. I agree that's not an ideal scenario, but it worked for me for last few years. Since all changes are performed on the database via Hibernate it seems that this approach has "some" value. Ultimately I'm planning to move to Testcontainers but at the moment I need to resolve above issue to bring back H2 tests to life.

Comment: I don't know enough about the Liquibase/H2 combination to provide a solution. It does seem strange that it is dropping a table to add a column, AFAIK H2 does not require that. Also I am not sure why there is `DROP TABLE "SCHEMA"."TABLE_COPY_3_186"` for ` ALTER TABLE schema.table ADD address_id INT`, unless there was some manual renaming done for the SO post.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. Just to clarify, I've depersonalized changeset and exception stack trace. But besides table name, schema name and author name replacement, everything remains the same. So YES it does perform `DROP TABLE "SCHEMA"."TABLE_COPY_3_186` for `ALTER TABLE schema.table ADD address_id INT`. I'll investigate further into that matter in few weeks if nothing comes up in this thread. For now I've applied workaround by adding a column at first creation of the table which is horrible.

Comment: > _"Since all changes are performed on the database via Hibernate it seems that this approach has "some" value"_ - that's exactly the reason why it doesn't. Since Hibernate generates the queries dynamically one can get [quite surprising results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452183/hibernate-produce-different-sql-for-every-query) even on the same database. The results of testing on different database types are not comparable. Hibernate is simply mature enough to mask this fact.